# MySQL append string

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

How can I append a string to the end of an existing table value? Let's say I have the table below:
[image]

And let's say that Maria Anders not only lived in Berlin but also Tokyo. How would I append the string 
" Tokyo" onto the City column where ContactName = Maria Anders?

P.S. I want to be able to append on to a null value as well. Thus ending up with just the one city.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a combination of [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) (to handle the `NULL` case):

```
UPDATE `table`
   SET `City` = IFNULL(CONCAT(`City`, " Tokyo"), "Tokyo")
 WHERE `ContactName` = "Maria Anders";
```

---

**However,** appending seems wrong. If you want multiple City values (a many-to-many relationship), you should have a separate table for cities and a separate table for person-city relationships. Read about [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: +1 I forgot you don't use `+` for string concatenation in MySQL.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I am going to try and have a separate table for the cities people live in. So as to make relations simpler. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer: No worries; hope you get it all sorted!

Comment: @Martin: Shame, as I rather liked your use of `COALESCE` (which, incidentally, is still valid :D)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have nested lists inside of a table. I would first create a table that associates each person with a unique ID. This is important in case you have someone else down the road with the same name.

```
ID  |  ContactName 
----+---------------
23  |  Maria Anders
```

Then have each location associated with an ID - For example:

```
ID  |  Address  |  City
----+-----------+------
```

Then when you need to add a new location for the same person, you can just add another value. For example:

```
ID  |  Address  |  City
----+-----------+------
23  | Foo ST.   | Baria
23  | Bar Ave.  | Fooia
```

Fetching the data and creating a list in your application/website will then be easy, as well as more flexible. Check out information on building one-to-many relationship tables via Google or the other places people suggested.