# How to add the string within string that contains specific characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a wordpress website and need to add `string rel="nofollow"` just after each specific link containing specific word (e.g. this-link). I have this string:

```
a href="http://www.this-link-is.com/ANYTHING"
```

and need `add rel="nofollow"` after each string that contains this-link:
      `a href="http://www.this-link-is.com/ANYTHING" rel="nofollow"`

so it should be something like

```
update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content, '%this-link%>', '%this-link% rel="nofollow">');
```

How could I do this? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524872/mysql-append-string

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.  You'll need to define it as a UDF, e.g.:

https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

Using the `REGEXP_REPLACE` UDF from that link, your query would then look like:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `wp_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`wp_content`, '(this-link[^"]+")', '\1 rel="nofollow')
WHERE `link` LIKE '%this-link%';
```